# how did conda install choose packages in continuum.io?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

There are several packages with the same version .How did conda install know to choose .

pandas with 0.10.1 version  has 5 package.Which will conda install choose.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recheck it. Versions are not same there is difference exist at python level.

- 0.10.1 -> py26
- 0.10.1 -> py27
- 0.10.1 -> py33

Comment: ，when you run "conda install pandas",where is the configuration file by which the system will choose py26 or py27 or py33.